# Perl - regex - I want to read and search each line for a string followed by a ";"

Tags: regex, perl

I'm playing and learning Perl so that I can read log files. I want to search every line and look for a string of alphanumeric followed by this `;` at the beginning of each line.

This is part of what I have:

```
 if ($line =~ /\S([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)/)
```

but I think this is wrong.

Please advise.

Comment: An alphabetic character is `\p{alpha}`.  A letter is `\pL` or `\p{letter}`.  A number is `\pN` or `\p{number}`.  A digit is `\d` or `\p{Nd}` or `\p{digit}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if ($line =~ /^[a-z0-9]+;/i) { ... }
```

`^` matches the start of a line. The `+` matches once or more. `/i` makes the search case-insensitive.

Answer (score 3):

"Alphanumeric" is a bit ambiguous now, since many people still infected with ASCII think it means A-Z with 0-9, but Perl thinks about it differently depending on the version ([Know your character classes under different semantics](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/01/know-your-character-classes/)). As with any regular expression, your job is to design a pattern the includes only what you want and doesn't exclude anything that you do want.

Also, many people still use the `^` to mean the beginning of the string, which is does if there's no `/m` flag. However, the [re](https://www.metacpan.org/module/re) module can now set default flags, so your regex might not be what you think it is when another programmer tries to be helpful.

I tend to write things like:

```
my $alphanum = qr/[a-z0-9]/i;
my $regex    = qr/
    \A              # absolute start of string
    (?:$alphanum)+  # I can change this elsewhere
    ;
    /x;

if( $line =~ $regex ) { ... }
```